# fancy arrows in fancypar

Tags: symbols, arrows

Could you help me to find an arrow symbol I found it in [`fancypar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancypar) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancypar/fancypar.pdf) using as items in blue (at the first page):

[image]

Comment: From [`manfnt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/manfnt), use `\manerrarrow`.

Comment: I can't find documentation How can I use other symbols ? thank you

Comment: The [minimal document](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dezXP.png) produces [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oO0J1.png).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I can't found documentation to explain manfnt if I want to use other symbols.

Comment: Click on the duplicate link. There you'll see a reference to the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive), where you can look at a whole bunch of symbols available in LaTeX across many packages. Specifically for [`manfnt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/manfnt), see Table 289 (p 89) of the [A4 symbol list](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: @Werner I have a trouble with symbols of `manfnt`.  [Your code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dezXP.png) produces a *pixelated* picture like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kniBh.png). Do you know what package i must load to fix this issue? I use *MikTeX 2.9* on Windows.

Comment: @skpblack: You must have some information reported in your `.log`. Use that as a starting point.